# Fifteen distinct positive integers

Tags: number-sequence

A set of $15$ distinct positive integers $a_1,a_2,a_3,\dots,a_{15}$ is such that for each $i$, $2\le i\le 15$, $a_i=a_{i-1}+i,a_i=a_{i-1}-i,a_i=a_{i-1}\times i$, or $a_i=a_{i-1}\div i$. If the largest of these $15$ integers is $19$, find all the others.

Comment: Ten such distinct positive integers, the largest of which is $13$, are $1, 2, 6, 10, 5, 11, 4, 12, 3, 13$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solutions:

> 1,<sub>+2</sub>,3,<sub>×3</sub>,9,<sub>+4</sub>,13,<sub>-5</sub>,8,<sub>+6</sub>,14,<sub>÷7</sub>,2,<sub>×8</sub>,16,<sub>-9</sub>,7,<sub>+10</sub>,17,<sub>-11</sub>,6,<sub>+12</sub>,18,<sub>-13</sub>,5,<sub>+14</sub>,19,<sub>-15</sub>,4
>  9,<sub>+2</sub>,11,<sub>+3</sub>,14,<sub>-4</sub>,10,<sub>÷5</sub>,2,<sub>+6</sub>,8,<sub>+7</sub>,15,<sub>-8</sub>,7,<sub>+9</sub>,16,<sub>-10</sub>,6,<sub>+11</sub>,17,<sub>-12</sub>,5,<sub>+13</sub>,18,<sub>-14</sub>,4,<sub>+15</sub>,19
>  10,<sub>-2</sub>,8,<sub>+3</sub>,11,<sub>+4</sub>,15,<sub>÷5</sub>,3,<sub>+6</sub>,9,<sub>-7</sub>,2,<sub>×8</sub>,16,<sub>-9</sub>,7,<sub>+10</sub>,17,<sub>-11</sub>,6,<sub>+12</sub>,18,<sub>-13</sub>,5,<sub>+14</sub>,19,<sub>-15</sub>,4
>  10,<sub>+2</sub>,12,<sub>-3</sub>,9,<sub>+4</sub>,13,<sub>-5</sub>,8,<sub>+6</sub>,14,<sub>÷7</sub>,2,<sub>×8</sub>,16,<sub>-9</sub>,7,<sub>+10</sub>,17,<sub>-11</sub>,6,<sub>+12</sub>,18,<sub>-13</sub>,5,<sub>+14</sub>,19,<sub>-15</sub>,4
>  11,<sub>-2</sub>,9,<sub>+3</sub>,12,<sub>÷4</sub>,3,<sub>+5</sub>,8,<sub>+6</sub>,14,<sub>÷7</sub>,2,<sub>×8</sub>,16,<sub>-9</sub>,7,<sub>+10</sub>,17,<sub>-11</sub>,6,<sub>+12</sub>,18,<sub>-13</sub>,5,<sub>+14</sub>,19,<sub>-15</sub>,4
>  11,<sub>+2</sub>,13,<sub>-3</sub>,10,<sub>+4</sub>,14,<sub>-5</sub>,9,<sub>+6</sub>,15,<sub>-7</sub>,8,<sub>+8</sub>,16,<sub>-9</sub>,7,<sub>+10</sub>,17,<sub>-11</sub>,6,<sub>+12</sub>,18,<sub>-13</sub>,5,<sub>+14</sub>,19,<sub>-15</sub>,4
>  12,<sub>-2</sub>,10,<sub>+3</sub>,13,<sub>-4</sub>,9,<sub>+5</sub>,14,<sub>-6</sub>,8,<sub>+7</sub>,15,<sub>-8</sub>,7,<sub>+9</sub>,16,<sub>-10</sub>,6,<sub>+11</sub>,17,<sub>-12</sub>,5,<sub>+13</sub>,18,<sub>-14</sub>,4,<sub>+15</sub>,19
>  12,<sub>+2</sub>,14,<sub>-3</sub>,11,<sub>+4</sub>,15,<sub>÷5</sub>,3,<sub>+6</sub>,9,<sub>-7</sub>,2,<sub>×8</sub>,16,<sub>-9</sub>,7,<sub>+10</sub>,17,<sub>-11</sub>,6,<sub>+12</sub>,18,<sub>-13</sub>,5,<sub>+14</sub>,19,<sub>-15</sub>,4
>  13,<sub>-2</sub>,11,<sub>+3</sub>,14,<sub>-4</sub>,10,<sub>÷5</sub>,2,<sub>+6</sub>,8,<sub>+7</sub>,15,<sub>-8</sub>,7,<sub>+9</sub>,16,<sub>-10</sub>,6,<sub>+11</sub>,17,<sub>-12</sub>,5,<sub>+13</sub>,18,<sub>-14</sub>,4,<sub>+15</sub>,19
>  13,<sub>-2</sub>,11,<sub>+3</sub>,14,<sub>-4</sub>,10,<sub>+5</sub>,15,<sub>-6</sub>,9,<sub>-7</sub>,2,<sub>×8</sub>,16,<sub>-9</sub>,7,<sub>+10</sub>,17,<sub>-11</sub>,6,<sub>+12</sub>,18,<sub>-13</sub>,5,<sub>+14</sub>,19,<sub>-15</sub>,4
>  13,<sub>+2</sub>,15,<sub>-3</sub>,12,<sub>÷4</sub>,3,<sub>+5</sub>,8,<sub>+6</sub>,14,<sub>÷7</sub>,2,<sub>×8</sub>,16,<sub>-9</sub>,7,<sub>+10</sub>,17,<sub>-11</sub>,6,<sub>+12</sub>,18,<sub>-13</sub>,5,<sub>+14</sub>,19,<sub>-15</sub>,4
>  13,<sub>+2</sub>,15,<sub>-3</sub>,12,<sub>-4</sub>,8,<sub>-5</sub>,3,<sub>+6</sub>,9,<sub>-7</sub>,2,<sub>×8</sub>,16,<sub>-9</sub>,7,<sub>+10</sub>,17,<sub>-11</sub>,6,<sub>+12</sub>,18,<sub>-13</sub>,5,<sub>+14</sub>,19,<sub>-15</sub>,4

Comment: The intended solution is the first above in which the first term of the sequence is 1.

Comment: Ah. That wasn't specified in the problem, so I provided all of them :)

Comment: So much the better!